# Gradle sync failed, (Operation not permitted)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, gradle, react-native-community-netinfo

Im facing this error in android studio Im using react-native with these dependency versions

`"react": "16.8.3", "react-native": "^0.59.10", "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^3.2.1",`

`/Users/sullah/Downloads/Projects/FrontEnd/team-lms-field-app-old/node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo/android/gradle.properties (Operation not permitted)`

the app is built in react-native and was working fine but since yesterday when I hit the run command `npx react-native run-android` the app gets installed on the device and then launches and crashes after debugging and opening it in the android studio I see the above issue with gradle. the metro bundler shows nothing at all and is kind of stuck attaching a snip of it too.
I also tried to clone a fresh project and it worked for the first time and when issuing the same command and running the app for the second time the app stops working(crashes).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to upgrade ur gradle version for me I did change it to 3.6.0 and  everything works fine now